# error pytube.exceptions.RegexMatchError: regex_search: could not find match for (?:v=|\/)([0-9A-Za-z_-]{11}).*

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytube

hi I have a kinda weird problem with my main.py
the problem is when I make the if statement search in the list as it's shown under it throws an error which I mentioned under and when i remove the in from if and type key = 'fniufn3'(as an ex.) the code works perfectly i don't know how to fix this problem I have been sitting for about 3 hours searching in many websites but no clear answer, if anything is not clear I will edit, By the way I'm Using python 3.
this is my code

```
from pytube import YouTube
import os
import webbrowser
from act_key import act_key

chrome = '"C:\\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\\chrome.exe"  %s'


def premium_user():
    link = input("Enter The Link ")
    yt = YouTube(link)
    stream = yt.streams.get_highest_resolution()
    stream.download()
    print("Download Has Been Completed Successfully")


def download():
    allfiles = os.listdir('C:\\Users\Abdelrhman Ayman\PycharmProjects\Youtube Video downloader')
    files = [fname for fname in allfiles if fname.endswith('.mp4')]
    number = len(files)
    link = input("Enter The Link ")
    if 'http' in link:
        print("Wait....")
    else:
        print('Enter A valid Link ')
        while True:
            download()
    if number >= 5:
        print("Subscribe Please For This Service")
        webbrowser.get(chrome).open('http://localhost:63342/Youtube%20Video%20downloader/Payment.html')
        key = input("Enter The Activation Key ")

        if key in act_key:
            premium_user()

        else:
            print("This Is Not A Valid Key")

    else:
        yt = YouTube(link)
        stream = yt.streams.get_highest_resolution()
        stream.download()
        print("You Can Download ", (4 - number), " More Times")
        print("Download Has Been Completed Successfully")


while True:
    download()
```

this is the act_key.py

```
act_key = ('F3S6-37EU-WRC2-V7V1','0K77-R7I6-C0GH-MB6C', 'D72I-YPLG-ZLTT-FKLA','QABM-P3XE-JJ56-9S5Q','EPR2-OAG5-R7D4-QZ8Q','XDA1-HF33-CAFS-ZFXG','CS1B-Y9YY-1JOW-DZDD','PVGO-0R20-OVXR-5WE0','LSQB-JHAI-FS29-LHKJ','7HRZ-KED9-CCQG-FDUW')
```

this is the error

```
"C:\Users\Abdelrhman Ayman\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe" "C:/Users/Abdelrhman Ayman/PycharmProjects/Youtube Video downloader/main.py"
Enter The Link https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jVgDHt2Elg8
Wait....
Subscribe Please For This Service
Enter The Activation Key XDA1-HF33-CAFS-ZFXG

Enter The Link Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Abdelrhman Ayman\PycharmProjects\Youtube Video downloader\main.py", line 47, in <module>
    download()
  File "C:\Users\Abdelrhman Ayman\PycharmProjects\Youtube Video downloader\main.py", line 34, in download
    premium_user()
  File "C:\Users\Abdelrhman Ayman\PycharmProjects\Youtube Video downloader\main.py", line 11, in premium_user
    yt = YouTube(link)
  File "C:\Users\Abdelrhman Ayman\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pytube\__main__.py", line 71, in __init__
    self.video_id = extract.video_id(url)
  File "C:\Users\Abdelrhman Ayman\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pytube\extract.py", line 133, in video_id
    return regex_search(r"(?:v=|\/)([0-9A-Za-z_-]{11}).*", url, group=1)
  File "C:\Users\Abdelrhman Ayman\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pytube\helpers.py", line 129, in regex_search
    raise RegexMatchError(caller="regex_search", pattern=pattern)
pytube.exceptions.RegexMatchError: regex_search: could not find match for (?:v=|\/)([0-9A-Za-z_-]{11}).*

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Is it safe to explicitly show your youtube premium activation key right here?

Comment: Inside `premium_user()` function, what is the link that you typed when `input()` is called? It doesn't appear on the error log.

Comment: yes I can show them I will edit

Comment: when the user enters the activation key and it's correct the premium function do the same function of download but without asking user for subscription (the user inputs the link of the video and it downloads directly)

Comment: i didn't typed anything python just quited me from the terminal with the exit code 1

Comment: I see what's happening. The problem is not with the PyTube API as the title refers to. As you mentioned, you didn't typed anything on the terminal, the program simply crashed. I think that it has something to do with the PyCharm that you're using. It's probably interferring in the way of the `input()` function, making it not wait for user input and returning something else.

Comment: Otherwise, the `input()` function should wait for user input, then a valid link could be passed to the `Youtube()` function.

Comment: My guess is that. Some problem with PyCharm and `input`, not the Youtube API.

Comment: Have you tried executing the same script without using PyCharm?

Comment: No I haven't tried doing that

Comment: I tried the code in pydroid 3 and the code worked without errors

Comment: Thanks for help , I didn't expected that the problem will be from pycharm anyway I will search for fixes for that issue and if I found a solution i will mention the link of the solution here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that when I copy the act_key pycharm adds a space at the end of the act key code and pycharm execute the premium user function so it enters the space to the input which needs a valid YouTube link so it causes the crash the solution is to not to copy the act key and try to change the act key to a shorter one or to write the act key in your terminal and make sure that there's no spaces after the last letter the problem actually from pycharm not the the python package .